# Won't delete or replace £ (pound) sign

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I'm trying to delete all the £ symbols in a text file (.csv) using sed, however it doesn't work and I've no clue as to why. Any suggestions?  Basically using:

```
sed -i 's/£//g' file.csv
```

Output of locale:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Update:

So, I don't know why sed wasn't working, but
    tr -d '\243' < inputfile
Does work! Thanks to @devnull for that!

Comment: This may help http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-ascii-control-codes-nonprintable/

Comment: Works on Mac, FYI. (But the `-i` option requires an additional extension argument before the replacement part, e.g. `''`)

Comment: Works on debian `testing`, too. May you post the output of `locale`!?

Comment: Added locale output. Thanks @Keyser, I'm on Linux so the -i option should be fine, in theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
sed "s/\xA3//" inputfile
```

Alternatively, you can use `tr`:

```
tr -d '\243' < inputfile
```

Comment: Yes indeed, no luck :( It's in UFT-8, but the terminal output shows it as a � and not a £, if that's any clue for..

Comment: The second 'tr' one works! Just out of curiosity, do you know why that one would work and not sed? Thanks for solving!

Comment: Maybe my sed is feeling under the weather! It's a mystery!

Comment: @ElliotReed Did you say `\XA3` instead of `\xA3` (note the case difference)?

Comment: @devnull It's weird but I couldn't get sed to work in my machine. I tried yours too. Not sure why.

Comment: It seems to be a locale specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/o\302\o243//g' file
```

N.B. if you are in doubt how sed sees a particular character use the `l` command and sed will display the character as it sees it (in this case in octal). e.g.

```
echo '£' | sed 'l'
\302\243$
```

The dollar following the octal codes represents the end of string.

For long strings use `l0` this will prevent wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hex code for the pound sign.

Seems like different versions in different platforms, *sed* act very differently. I just got the GNU version and works fine.

Before using sed, one should read the section "[When should I NOT use sed](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq6.html#6.4)"

Comment: Thanks! I get the error= sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated address regex

Comment: @ElliotReed I removed the suggestion as I just tried and also getting a parse error. Not sure why.